# UINT_MAX->float->uint32_t Results in 0 on VC++

Tags: c++, floating-point, undefined-behavior

As part of some work to port some code to windows I came across an issue where a cast of uint32_t max value -> float -> uint32_t resulted in 0 when building with the visual c++.
I distilled the problem down to a simple program that shows the issue when run through different compilers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    uint32_t r1 = numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max();
    float r2 = static_cast<float>(numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max());
    uint32_t r3 = static_cast<uint32_t>(static_cast<float>(numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()));


    cout << "r1 = " << r1 << endl
    << "r2 = " << r2 << endl
    << "r3 = " << r3 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When this is run through http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ the output for r3 is 0 but when run through https://ideone.com/ylf74N r3 is the max value.

I'm guessing that there's a +1 happening in the conversion back to uint32_t when it's UINT_MAX but I'm wondering if anyone knows why or what precisely is happening?

Comment: Interestingly uint32_t r3 = static_cast<uint32_t>(r2); still gives the wrong output (the original value) on the second compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When converting from an integer type to a real type the result may be inexact and rounded towards the closest representable (above or below the original value) in the real type. In your case float has 24 bits in its mantissa part, so, 0xFFFFFFFF isn't going to survive the conversion unchanged as it needs 32 bits of mantissa. So, it can convert to 0x100000000 (closest above). If that happens, you'll be converting 0x100000000 from float to your 32-bit unsigned type. And this conversion results in *undefined behavior* (which includes unpredictable/unreliable results) because the value is outside of the range of the 32-bit unsigned type.

You also get UB with the other compiler, you're just unaware of it. Circumvent optimization by introducing *volaitle* (in declarations of r1, r2 and r3) and you'll see it (ideone.com/1CCat8).

Comment: I *thought* that a conversion to an unsigned type was always defined - wraparound happens. Am I incorrect here?

Comment: @Bathsheba: that's only when the source type is integral.

Answer (score 2):

On your system it appears that `float` is a 32 bit type, probably IEEE754 (but note that the standard does not insist on that).

`numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()` is 4294967295.

This is too big for your float. (The largest odd number that can be accommodated in an IEEE754 32 bit floating point is 8388607).

So your number gets rounded up to 4294967296. (This is the closet number that can be accommodated).

Of course, on converting this back to `uint32_t` causes it to wrap around to 0.

As for the other system, we know the `float` is 32 bits due to the `sizeof` output. The compiler is making an optimisation in error.

Comment: so is there a particular reason that other compilers give max when converting back?

Comment: A `float` *could* be 64 bit.

Comment: @JasonHorsburgh: The Standard does not say what should happen when converting a floating-point number to an integer type too small to hold it.  Some implementations "peg" the result to the range of the integer type (so any floating-point value greater than 4294967295 would yield 4294967295); others may peg the result to a larger integer type and then mod-reduce it.